# Mysql display field name where value is specific

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+------------------------+-------+------+-------+------+
| user                   | TELPE | CRS2 | MECAN | GOPI |
+------------------------+-------+------+-------+------+
| user1.foo@my-email.com | NULL  | NULL | 1     | NULL |
+------------------------+-------+------+-------+------+
| user2.foo@my-email.com | 1     | NULL | 1     | NULL |
+------------------------+-------+------+-------+------+
```

I'm struggling to find the request that would returned the columns name for a specific user where the value is 1.

Select manually column is not an option as if there is only 4 columns today, 
there'll may be 300 next week.

for instance the search for the user1  would give this this result:

```
+-------------+
| Books       |
+-------------+
| MECAN       |
+-------------+
```

and for user2:

```
+-------------+
| Books       |
+-------------+
| TELPE       |
+-------------+
| MECAN       |
+-------------+
```

My Mysql skills are not very high so any help is appreciated,

Many thanks by advance.

Comment: Please provide the expected output...:)

Comment: Which value?...

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "Select manually column is not an option as if there is only 4 columns today, there'll may be 300 next week."  that changes things alot let me think about it for a while.

Comment: The fact that you *want* the column name suggests that your design is poor. PS Read also about pivoting, which move values between column values & column names.

Comment: @Processor updated mine answer the query generate the dynamic SQL based on the number off the columns in the table user... ive tryed to break down the complete complex query and explain it.. But stackoverflow has a answer max length limit and i couldn't explain more about the last part in mine answer..

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the columns into rows this process is called unpivot. 
You can do that with UNIONS.

**Query**

```
 SELECT
     USER
   , TELPE AS 'column_value'
   , 'TELPE' AS 'column_source' 
  FROM 
   users 
  WHERE
   TELPE = 1 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     USER
   , CRS2 AS 'column_value'
   , 'CRS2' AS 'column_source'
  FROM 
   users
  WHERE
   CRS2 = 1    

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     USER
   , MECAN AS 'column_value'
   , 'MECAN' AS 'column_source'
  FROM 
   users
  WHERE
   MECAN = 1 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     USER
   , GOPI AS 'column_value'
   , 'GOPI' AS 'column_source'
  FROM 
   users
  WHERE
   GOPI = 1
```

**Result**

```
user                    column_value  column_source  
----------------------  ------------  ---------------
user2.foo@my-email.com  1             TELPE          
user1.foo@my-email.com  1             MECAN          
user2.foo@my-email.com  1             MECAN
```

Now we can use this query as a delivered table to filter the results you need.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT 
  column_source
FROM ( 

  SELECT
     USER
   , TELPE AS 'column_value'
   , 'TELPE' AS 'column_source' 
  FROM 
   users 
  WHERE
   TELPE = 1 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     USER
   , CRS2 AS 'column_value'
   , 'CRS2' AS 'column_source'
  FROM 
   users
  WHERE
    CRS2 = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     USER
   , MECAN AS 'column_value'
   , 'MECAN' AS 'column_source'
  FROM 
   users
  WHERE
   MECAN = 1 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     USER
   , GOPI AS 'column_value'
   , 'GOPI' AS 'column_source'
  FROM 
   users
  WHERE
   GOPI = 1 
) 
 AS
  users
WHERE
   users.user = 'user1.foo@my-email.com'
 AND
   users.column_value = 1
```

**Result**

```
| column_source |
|---------------|
|         MECAN |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ed091/19

**EDITED**

> Select manually column is not an option as if there is only 4 columns today, there'll may be 300 next week.

Then you need to move to dynamic SQL generating.

First when are going to need a number generator this query will generate 1000 numbers from 2 to 1001. 
Why we need a number generator will become more clear later on.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  @row := @row + 1 AS number
FROM ( 
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
)
 AS row1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
) 
  AS row2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
) 
  AS row3            
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT @row := 1
) 
 AS init_user_param
```

**Result**

### number

```
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
  10
....
....
 990
 991
 992
 993
 994
 995
 996
 997
 998
 999
1000
1001
```

Now we need a way to get all the column fore the table users.

**Query**

```
  SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMN_NAME
  FROM 
   information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE
     TABLE_NAME = 'users'
   AND
     TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'performance_schema'
```

**Result**

```
COLUMN_NAME                 
----------------------------
user,TELPE,CRS2,MECAN,GOPI
```

Now we want to generate a unique list like

```
user  TELPE
user  CRS2
...
...
user  GOPI
```

Now we combine the number generator with the query to get the columns.
We also use SUBSTRING_INDEX to spilt the comma separated values.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME, ',', 1), ',', -1) column1
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME, ',', generator.number), ',', -1) column2
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMN_NAME
  FROM 
   information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE
     TABLE_NAME = 'users'
   AND
     TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'performance_schema'
)
 AS user_column

CROSS JOIN (

    SELECT 
      @row := @row + 1 AS number
    FROM ( 
      SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )
     AS row1
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) 
      AS row2
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) 
      AS row3            
    CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT @row := 1
    ) 
     AS init_user_param  
)  
  AS generator
```

**Result**

```
column1  column2  
-------  ---------
user     TELPE    
user     CRS2     
user     MECAN    
user     GOPI
```

To make to SQL generation completely dynamic

**Query**

```
SET @sql_union = NULL;

SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(
   CONCAT(
    "
     SELECT
       ",column1,"
     , ",column2," AS 'column_value'
     , '",column2,"' AS 'column_source' 
     FROM 
       users 
      WHERE
       ",column2," = 1 
    " 
  )
  SEPARATOR 'UNION ALL'
 )
FROM ( 

  SELECT
    DISTINCT
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME, ',', 1), ',', -1) column1
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_NAME, ',', generator.number), ',', -1) column2
  FROM ( 

    SELECT 
     GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMN_NAME
    FROM 
     information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE
       TABLE_NAME = 'users'
    AND
      TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'performance_schema'
  )
   AS user_columns

  CROSS JOIN (

    SELECT 
      @row := @row + 1 AS number
    FROM ( 
      SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    )
     AS row1
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) 
      AS row2
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
    ) 
      AS row3            
    CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT @row := 1
    ) 
     AS init_user_param  
  )  
    AS generator
) 
 AS generator_union_sql INTO @sql_union;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
"
SELECT
 DISTINCT 
  column_source
FROM ( 
"
,@sql_union, 
"
) 
 AS
  users
WHERE
   users.user = 'user1.foo@my-email.com'
 AND
   users.column_value = 1
"
);

PREPARE queryUser FROM @sql;
EXECUTE queryUser;
```

**Result**

```
column_source  
---------------
MECAN
```

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for all you answers.
In fact there is somehting I did not said, the columns will grow drastically.
So a search column by column manually is not an option. May by is there is a "for" function in mysql. Because there is only 4 columns today but may be 300 next week.
then I'm searching for a result like:
+-------------+
| column_name |
+-------------+
| TELPE       |
| MECAN     |
+-------------+
for users  2

Comment: Please update the question with that information don't comment on mine answer with question updates.

Comment: Hi all,
 many thanks for your help, Not yet solved but with your help i'm on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for something like

```
SELECT user, if(telpe=1,"TELPE","") as rTELPE, if(CRS2=1,"CRS2","") as rCRS2 from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I updated my request, to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand for your question is:

```
SELECT 'TELPE' FROM yourTable WHERE telpe = 1 AND user = 'user1.foo@my-email.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CRS2 ' FROM yourTable WHERE crs2 = 1 AND user = 'user1.foo@my-email.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MECAN' FROM yourTable WHERE mecam = 1 AND user = 'user1.foo@my-email.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOPI' FROM yourTable WHERE gopi = 1 AND user = 'user1.foo@my-email.com'
```